What is the fastest way to serialize and deserialize a list of bools
orjson is already quite fast but I'm curious if there's an even faster way of getting from [1, 0, 0, 1] to 'intermediary_string' and back again, without storing any metadata separately (such as length).

Does it need to be a str string or can it be bytes? And do you care about size or just about speed? And how long are your real lists? And you say bools but your example contains 0 and 1. Which is it?

You can serialize a list of small integers into a byte string with the bytes constructor, and deserialize the byte string back into a list of integers with the list constructor. Use bytearray instead of bytes for even better performance:
Below is a benchmark:
from timeit import timeit
from orjson import dumps, loads

def serialize_deserialize_json(a):
    return loads(dumps(a))

def serialize_deserialize_bytes(a):
    return list(bytes(a))

def serialize_deserialize_bytearray(a):
    return list(bytearray(a))

a = [1, 0, 0, 1] * 10
for f in serialize_deserialize_json, serialize_deserialize_bytes, serialize_deserialize_bytearray:
    print(f.__name__, timeit('f(a)', globals=globals()))

Sample output:
serialize_deserialize_json 0.7790328999981284
serialize_deserialize_bytes 0.6200750999851152
serialize_deserialize_bytearray 0.4932393000344746


bytearray() is still a native type though right? I need to deserialize to a string or raw bytes so that I can pass it around.
When I do list(bytearray(bytes(bytearray([1,0,1,1])))) it takes longer than orjson. Also interestingly on my PC, bytes() is slower than orjson: 0.41908463096478954 vs 0.48489161097677425.

bytearray can be used just about anywhere bytes is expected, so I don't think you need to explicitly convert it to bytes first to pass it around.

Made me ask why bytearray is faster than bytes.

Probably converting the booleans to a bit array and serializing the bit array to bytes:
from bitarray import bitarray

input = [1, 0, 0, 1]
ba = bitarray(input)
serialized = ba.tobytes()

ba = bitarray()
ba.frombytes(serialized)
deserialized_list = ba.tolist()

A bit array is a data structure that's useful for storing an manipulating binary values which can be represented as 0 or 1. Each value in the original input is stored as a single bit, making it highly space efficient.
Furthermore, operations such as setting, clearing, and toggling bits are done using highly efficient bitwise operations that run in O(1) time.

Bizarrely, orjson is still faster than using bitarray()...
